# Identify Java variables from ANTLR AST

Tags: java, variables, antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to list all variables used in Java source code using ANTLR4. For following source the result should be `a,b,i`.

```
class Item {}
class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 3;
        int b;
        b = a + 1;
        Item i = new Item();
        i = new Item();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Using [the official grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) I can extract AST like this: ([view larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDSSU.png)) [image: AST grammar]

The problem is that I don't know how to distinguish variable and e.g. `System` as they both are marked as `expression -> primary`.

I guess this is a common problem but I couldn't find any suitable answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm no ANTLR expert, but scanning your image I would suggest the `variableDeclaratorId` is the value to seek.

Comment: to distinguish var from func from type etc... you need a symbol table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the `enterVariableDeclarator(...)` method from the `JavaBaseListener` to get a hold of the text `variableDeclaratorId` matches:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String source = "class Item {}\n" +
                "class First {\n" +
                "    public static void main(String[] args) {\n" +
                "        int a = 3;\n" +
                "        int b;\n" +
                "        b = a + 1;\n" +
                "        Item i = new Item();\n" +
                "        i = new Item();\n" +
                "        System.out.println(b);\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

        final JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(source));
        final JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        final List<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();

        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new JavaBaseListener() {
            // variableDeclarator
            //     :   variableDeclaratorId ('=' variableInitializer)?
            //     ;
            @Override
            public void enterVariableDeclarator(@NotNull JavaParser.VariableDeclaratorContext ctx) {
                variables.add(ctx.variableDeclaratorId().getText());
            }
        }, parser.compilationUnit());

        System.out.printf("variable=%s", variables);
    }
}
```

would print:

```
variable=[a, b, i]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply - I have onw more questin: what if I need variables in one particular block? Some variables defined earlier may occur there and `variableDeclarator` wouldn't do the trick.

Comment: @petrbel, add some flag inside your `JavaBaseListener` that keeps track of the code blocks.